# it should return the boolean value `True`,or`False`. but it doesn't return anything

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, string-comparison, string-length

```
a=[1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5]
for i in a:
  even=[]
  odd=[]
  for j in a:
      if(j%2==0):
        even.append(j)
      else:
        odd.append(j)

def compareList(even,odd):
  if(len(odd) > len(even)):
      return True
  else:
      return False
```

why doesnt it return True?

Comment: Whats the second for-loop doing? Where do you call `compareList`?

Comment: `compareList` is never called.

Comment: The outer loop is unnecessary. It will repeat the same code `len(a)` times and giving the same output as just one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This code works. You can use only the inner for loop.

```
a=[1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5]
even=[]
odd=[]
for j in a:
    if(j%2==0):
      even.append(j)
    else:
      odd.append(j)

def compareList(even,odd):
  if(len(odd) > len(even)):
      return True
  else:
      return False
  
print(compareList(even,odd))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).